# What are the powers of "Staff of Living Tribunal"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

In Doctor Strange (2016) movie, *Staff of Living Tribunal* was displayed. Living Tribunal is a multiverse being appeared in the comics. What are the powers of his staff? For example, *Vaulting Boots of Valtorr* allows you to jump in the mid-air and *Eye of Agamotto* allows you to reverse/fast-forward time.

Comment: Theoretically, Eye of Agamotto is actually a gateway to other dimensions (as seen in comic books). I keep on wondering why it was shown differently in the movies

Answer (score 6):

The Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki has this to say about *The Staff of the Living Tribunal*:

> The weapon can extended to segments similar to chain-links, allowing it to be used as a whip or flail. It can also exert greater force than the user can exert, as it can send opponents flying when struck with it and can support the user's weight without breaking, which allows it to be used to swing from structures.[(1)](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Staff_of_the_Living_Tribunal)

The staff's powers mainly exist to augment the combat effectiveness of the user. As of this time, the Marvel Cinematic Universe hasn't revealed any additional powers of the staff.

In the Marvel Comics Universe, the Staff appears to have much the same function, however it's abilities entail "emit[ing] a lash of amber energy."[(2)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Staff_of_the_Living_Tribunal)

Comment: Wiki is just some random user **describing what they see in the movie**